# DataAdapter Update method batch updates multiple rows

Tags: insert, rows, dataadapter

I have a Problem with DataAdapter Update method :

this is insert code for each row:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtTESTDB = dsTESTDB.Tables["dstblTESTDB"];
        drTblTESTDB = dtTESTDB.NewRow();
        drTblTESTDB.BeginEdit();
        drTblTESTDB["ID"] = txtID.Text;
        drTblTESTDB["Name"] = txtName.Text;
        drTblTESTDB["Family"] = txtFamily.Text;
        dtTESTDB.Rows.Add(drTblTESTDB);
        dtTESTDB = dsTESTDB.Tables[0].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
        dtlAdd = dtTESTDB;
        drTblTESTDB.EndEdit();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(txtID.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", txtFamily.Text);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = SQLConnection;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblTESTDB 
           (ID,Name,Family) values (@ID,@Name,@Family)";
        cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
        da.InsertCommand = cmd;
     }
```

now,I want update database after insert multiple rows with :

```
private void btnSynchronize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            da.UpdateBatchSize = 0;// dttblAdd.Rows.Count;
            da.Update(dtlAdd);
            dsTESTDB.AcceptChanges();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sqlEX.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.ToString());
        }
    }
```

this code work by one row insert without Error ,but if insert two or more record (rows) at a time , DataAdapter insert only last row into DATABASE and throw Exception.
why ?

(sorry - I can't Speak or Writing English very well)

Answer (score 0):

UpdateBatchSize = 0 may be the problem. You need to set it to those many rows as the row count.